# Why can 10.3.1 import a 2MB excel file, but 10.4.0 cannot, with the same commands and file?

Tags: import, java, excel, version-10.4

### Here is the code:

```
(*Import data from a 2 MB Excel file*)

(*First increase memory for large Excel files*)

<< JLink`;

InstallJava[];

ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", JVMArguments -> "-Xmx2048m"];

(*Now import the dataset*)

Clear[data];

data = Import["dataset.xlsx"][[1]];

Dimensions[data]
```

---

This code works fine in 10.3.1, but hangs in 10.4.0. Why???

Comment: Please provide an example Excel file that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I have not been able to learn how to upload the Excel file. Any tips?

Comment: @Michael Just upload it to any filehosting like https://www.sendspace.com/ .

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just uploaded the example Excel file to sendspace.com. The file is named dataset.xlxs, and the description is "Michael for MMA Stack Exchange."

Comment: @Michael You should publish here the URL you got after uploading the file, not the file name.

Comment: I'm clearly a newbie! Here is the URL: https://www.sendspace.com/file/8cmaoh

Comment: Importing xls files is more stable than importing xlsx ones .

Answer (score 7):

From Wolfram support: the reason 10.4.0 cannot import the excel file:
the command `ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "java", JVMArguments -> "-Xmx2048m"];`
is incorrect for 10.4.0. The correct command is:
`ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx2048m"];`.